# Posting HTML code at Stack Overflow without editor

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, iphone, ipad

Is there anyway around it? Since the editor doesn't work on iPad and iPhone, how does one post HTML code?

Should be a good idea since such devices are more and more common.

Answer (score 3):

If you enter a new line, and put 4 spaces, it will read the following text as code.

example:

```
I put 4 spaces before this line. Now it reads as code.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = new Bar();
```

it seems like posting code is fine from the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I keep the four-space-character indent in Pastebot and paste liberally.